# Change TS type of variable used in JSX return part of React component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I have a React component which renders navigation of profile page. User can have two states, one is customer, second is seller. Seller has more elements in menu, since he needs to set up products and other things. But I am fighting with typescript and how to tell him, that when user is seller, he has additional properties in object returned from api.

Is it possible to change type of user variable in JSX in some king of nice way, when user has property `isSeller: true`?

Here are my types:

```
import type { TDeliveryInformation } from '../../pages/OrderCreate'

export interface TCustomer {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
  email: string
  phone: string
  bornDate: string
  isSeller: boolean
  deliveryInformation: TDeliveryInformation
}

export interface TSeller extends TCustomer {
  ico: string
  firmName: string
  ....
}
```

Here is query which uses these two types in return type:

```
    import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query'
    import { api } from '../../index'
    import type { TCustomer, TSeller } from '../../../@types/user/user'
    
    const useMeQuery = () => 
      useQuery({
        queryKey: ['me'],
        queryFn: () => api().get(`me`).json<TCustomer | TSeller>(),
      })
    
    
    export default useMeQuery
```

And here is basic example of what I am trying to achieve in React component:

```
import { NavLink, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next'
import useMeQuery from '../../api/query/user/useMeQuery'
import Loader from '../../components/reusableComponents/Loader'

const User = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation()
  const {
    data: userInfo,
    isLoading: userBeingLoaded,
    isError: userError,
  } = useMeQuery()

  if (userBeingLoaded) return <Loader />
  if (userError) return 'Error happened'
  if (!userInfo) return null

  return (
    <div className="wrapper-width mx-auto mt-10">
      <div className="flex">
        <div>
          <h2>
            {userInfo.isSeller
              {/* Here I need to tell typescript that firmName exists (it is TSeller type and not TCustomer type), because user is seller */}
              ? userInfo.firmName
              : `${userInfo.firstName} ${userInfo.lastName}`}
          </h2>
        </div>
        <Outlet />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default User
```

This is the error I am getting:

[image]

Comment: Hi! Please **reduce** the code in the question to a [mcve] demonstrating the problem. There's a **lot** of extraneous information and code above, and it's a bit disjointed, making it difficult to help you.

Comment: Fundamentally, yes, it's possible to make TypeScript understand that something can be a `TCustomer` or `TSeller` based on a property like `isSeller` using [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions). The topic is well-covered here on SO if you search for that term.

Comment: Here's an example: https://tsplay.dev/wXODDW Hope that helps!